# Modified Quickselect - Proving linear time

Tags: recurrence-relation

As we know, Quickselect chooses a 'random' element in order to partition the array around that element in every iteration.

Assume the random element is at most the $\frac{1}{k}\cdot n$ largest element, and at least the $\frac{k-1}{k}\cdot n$ largest element, for some constant $k>1$.

I'm asked to prove that under those terms, Quickselect will run in linear time.

Here is how far I've got:

We know that for each iteration, there exists $r_i \in \mathbb{R}$ such that:   $\frac{1}{k}\cdot n\leq r_i\cdot n \leq \frac{k-1}{k}\cdot n$, this lets us know that:
$$
T(n)=T(r_1\cdot n)+O(n)
$$

but also, we know that:
$$ T(n)\leq T(\frac{k-1}{k}\cdot n)+O(n)$$
I was not able to continue further than this, I'm aware that I need to reach some sort of summation equation.

Comment: IMO, you swapped "at most" and "at least".

Comment: Do you mean $\frac kn$ overall, or $\frac kn$ on every recursive call ?

Comment: Thank you Yves, but this question is old and unfortunatly, I no longer remember the details of this, it seems I have forgot to mark it as 'completed'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by proving by induction that there exists a constant $A$ such that for all $n\geqslant 0$, $T(n) \leqslant Akn$.

Note that the constant $A$ can be chosen depending on $T(1)$ and such that the $\mathcal{O}(n)$ in your relation is $\leqslant An$.

Comment: I've tried this for quite some time yet this doesn't seem to help me prove.

I'm stuck on understanding how to express every iteration using $T(n)$

What i've got is that:
$$
T(\frac{k-1}{k} \cdot n)=T(\frac{k-1}{k} \cdot \frac{k-1}{k} \cdot n)+O(\frac{k-1}{k} \cdot n)
$$
I'm not sure how to move on from this, A colleague told me to find a way to turn this into a sum series, yet I'm not sure on how to do so, and what benefits will it get me.

Comment: Use an induction: suppose that for all $m<n$, $T(m) \leqslant Akm$, and use it to prove $T(n) \leqslant Akn$.